# How can I set Custom Button where I want on UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have a View With UINavigationBar

Navigation Bar only permits me the button at fix position

With Fix Position at the sides of the navigation bar..

I want to customize the position of button...
Any Idea...will help me
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customize the position of the buttons on a UINavigationItem, you only can set the rightBarButtonItem and leftBarButtonItem.

If you really need this, consider using a toolbar instead.

If you need a back button just like the navigation bar's back button, create a custom button and use an image.

Here's a [PSD](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-gui-psd/) that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can position custom buttons within the UINavigationItem. This is how I added three buttons to the right:

```
// create a toolbar to have three buttons in the right (thanks Mart!)
tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 157, 44.01)];

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 1.0, 157.0, 44.1)];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NavigationBarBackground" ofType:@"png"]]];
[tools addSubview:imgView];
[tools sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
[tools setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:127/255.0 green:184/255.0 blue:72/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[imgView release];

// create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                       initWithTitle:@"Filter" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showFilter:)];

[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
      initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Map.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showMap:)];

[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
      initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Favourite.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(saveSearch:)];
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

[buttons release];

rightBarButton = nil;
rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;
```